# How to add Core Data to an existing project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am currently working though [this tutorial](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2009/12/adding-core-data-existing-iphone-projects/), that explains how to add Core Data to an existing project.

I am up to the part titled

**AppDelegate.m**

It says this:

> Implement applicationDocumentsDirectory, and explicitly write accessor methods for each new property as opposed to simply using the
>   @synthesize keyword.  Note in the persistentStoreCoordinator accessor
>   there is a location where you must name the SQLite file used for the
>   store; this should most likely be your project name. Remember to
>   properly release each object in dealloc:

I do not understand what this part is asking me to do

> Implement applicationDocumentsDirectory, and explicitly write accessor methods for each new property as opposed to simply using the
>   @synthesize keyword.

From what I can tell its asking me to implement the variables differently from how I normally do them with the @synthesize.. but im not sure how else to do it...if someone could help me out that would be awesome.

Here is my property code

```
//Core Data
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

Comment: opps.. sorry beryllium what did I miss?

Comment: nothing, it's just a text formatting (quote instead of code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what that particular paragraph is saying is that you need to create custom getters for your CoreData ivars.

For instance, if you look at a fresh new template project created by Xcode, you will notice that all of the CoreData properties have their custom getters set, and they lazily instantiate/create the ivars the first time you access them.

For instance, the method below checks if your managedObjectContext ivar is not nil, in which case the context has already been created so the getter method will simply return it to the calling method (which is typically you accessing the `managedObjectContext` property with `self.managedObjectProperty`)

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil)
       return _managedObjectContext
    _managedObjectContext = ...
}
```

The applicationsDocumentDirectory method is just a convenience method that returns the path to the documents directory which will then be used by your persistent store coordinator to set the path for your CoreData database file.

Your best bet is to create a new project and copy the entire CoreData stack from the AppDelegate onto your existing project. You will then need to create a managed object model and make sure you have set the name correctly in the NSManagedObjectModel method, then you should be good to go.

Comment: right. what a pain in the bum.. lol oh well I will try that shortly I guess...  that you for outlining whats going on tho.

Comment: @C.Johns CoreData is great but the boilerplate stuff required to get it up and running is a pain. Have a look at MagicalRecord for a great framework that makes it very easy for you to get started. I'd still advise that you get a better understanding of what happens under the hood before getting into MagicalRecord but definitely give it a try.

Comment: cheers. yea I think subconsciously I have been trying to avoid coredata so far.. and I have finally got to the point where I have decided I need it.. so yea trying to get into it now but so much work is done behind the scenes its hard to understand exactly whats going on.. but Im sure ill get there. hanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You can clean up the template Core Data code a lot.  The references to `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and `NSManagedObjectModel` are not needed.  I tend to roll up all three into a single method to make the code a little more concise.

```
@interface AppDelegate()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize managedObjectContext = $managedObjectContext;

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
  if ($managedObjectContext) return $managedObjectContext;

  NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Example" withExtension:@"momd"];
  NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
  NSAssert1(mom, @"%@:%@ No model to generate a store from", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
  NSURL *libraryURL = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
  NSURL *url = [libraryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Example.storedata"];
  NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
  NSAssert(coordinator, @"Failed to initialize coordinator");

  NAssert1([coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSXMLStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:nil error:&error], @"Error: %@", error);

  $managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
  [$managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

  return $managedObjectContext;
}
```

With that code you have a class continuation that handles the ivar.  We use a synthesize so that we can talk directly to the ivar in the get accessor.

Since the MOM and PSC can be accessed via the MOC there is no need to keep extra references to them around.

Answer (score 1):

Even with `@property` declarations, you can still implement the accessors however you like.

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

Comment: so I don't need the @synthesize? it i have the @property declaration in the header file?

Comment: crazy. because atm I got errors all over the show. weird stuff that from my limited experience says should work, but is not.